# Why i'm getting strange video file when using ffmpeg and pipes to create video file in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, video, ffmpeg

The goal here is to create a compressed mp4 video file in real time.
I'm saving screenshots as bitmaps type on my hard disk.
And i want to create mp4 file and compress the mp4 video file in real time.

The problem is the end the video file i get looks very strange.
This is the result: [Strange Video File](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdxPus-Xv1k&feature=youtu.be)

The class that i'm using the ffmpeg with arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            Logger.Write("workingDirectory: " + workingDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);
            Logger.Write("FfmpegFilename: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {

                string outPath = pathFileName;
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                //psi.Arguments = @"-framerate 1/5 -i -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r" + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            try
            {
                int length;
                // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

                int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
                // Get the address of the first line.
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
                length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

                //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
                int j = bmp.Height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                    j--;
                }
                p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            p.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then i'm using the method PushFrame here in this class:

```
public Bitmap GetScreenShot(string folder, string name)
    {
        _screenShot = new Bitmap(GetScreen());
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        string ingName = folder + name +  images.counter.ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
        _screenShot.Save(ingName,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        fmpeg.PushFrame(_screenShot);
        _screenShot.Dispose();

        return _screenShot;
    }
```

The Bitmaps on the hard disk are fine i can edit/open see them.
When using command prompt and manually type ffmpeg command it does compress and create a mp4 video file.

But when using the Ffmpeg class i did with the PushFrame method it's creating this strange video file.

This is a link for my OneDrive with 10 screenshots images files for testing:

[screenshots rar](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1345&authkey=!AP6_vdjPjYPo-8Q&ithint=file%2Crar)

Sample screenshot from the video file when playing the video file:
Looks very choppy. The Bitmaps on the hard disk each one is 1920x1080 and Bit depth 32

But it dosen't look like that in the video file:

[image: choppy image]

This is the arguments i'm using:

```
psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
```

The video size is very small 1.24 MB

Comment: You're telling ffmpeg to expect a yuv420p stream but you're pushing rgb. Try with '-pix_fmt rgb24'

Comment: Ely it didn't work. I'm getting the same result same video as in the link in my question just this time the noisy color is now gray.

Comment: This is a link to my OneDrive to a rar file with 10 screenshots images for testing. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1345&authkey=!AP6_vdjPjYPo-8Q&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: Your BMPs pixel format is bgra (you can check that when opening the .bmp file in ffmpeg), that means there are 4 bytes per pixel. Can you try sending these 4 and setting '-pix_fmt bgra' ?

Comment: Ely this is working. bgra. But the quality looks bad. It dosent look like 1920x1080.

Comment: Ely the video size is very small 1.24MB but that's maybe fine. But the quality of the video is very bad. Added to my question a screenshot from the video and what i did.

Comment: Now you shifted your problem from ffmpeg not knowing what to encode to one of quality. Try asking another question! Basically, you have to parametrize ffmpeg to control the video codec you are using for output.

Comment: You're encoding with mpeg4 without specifying a quality parameter so the bad quality isn't surprising. I'd recommend using libx264 (H.264 codec) and setting crf to something like 20. (-c:v libx264 -crf 20). If you really want mpeg4, increase the quality with '-q:v 1'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both, `-f rawvideo` which indicates the kind of container you are using for your input, and `-vcodec rawvideo` which does the same for the video data you are pushing to `ffmpeg`. Otherwise, ffmpeg will try to detect the type of container you are using, and that probably won't work as expected.

Also, as @Ely commented, you need to set the `-pix_fmt rgb24`, as that is the format of the images you are sending.

Also note that you can get better information about what ffmpeg is doing by using the `-v debug` parameter.

Comment: I changed to the -pix_fmt rgb24 already. Could you show me an example about how to set both -f rawvideo and -vcodec rawvideo ? How and where ? Should i set them both in the Arguments ?

Comment: `psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;`